# Compare 2 csv with python and add a new Column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to compare two csv files and add a new column on `df_g` with the `Price` column of `df`.
I suppose I need to read line for line of the 2 csv but I don't know how I can do it so I try with it:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test2.csv')
df_g = pd.read_csv('test_hecho.csv')
if (df_g['Sitio'] == df['Sitio'] and df_g['Country'] == df['Country']):
    df_g['Bidfloor'] = df['Price']
df_g.to_csv('aaa.csv')
```

A possible answer is:
`df_g['Bidfloor'] = df_g[['Sitio','Country']].merge(df,how='left').Price`but I need to change the `=`to `= or part of`. Is it possible??

Comment: `df_g['Bidfloor']=df_g[['Sitio','Country']].merge(df,how='left').Price`

Comment: and if I need to do the same but instead of `==` I need to check if it is `==' or part of.. I mean, if `df_g['Country']`is `US - United States` and df['Country']`is ÙS - United States/CA - Canada`@Wen

Comment: Then you need provide the data

Comment: I mean instead of == something like is "equal or part of" @Wen

Comment: this involve more calculation , is that possible for you to create a sample data

Comment: `(df_g['Sitio'].str[:8].str.lower() == df['Sitio'].str[:8].str.lower())` this will make the stings lowercase and check the first 8 characters of each string. You can also select middle parts of a string to see if they match: `df_g['Sitio'].str[6:17].str.lower() == df['Sitio'].str[6:17].str.lower() `

Comment: when I have for example `a = '123' b = '2'`and I do `b<=a`the answer is True so I need something like this. I mean : `df_g['Bidfloor'] <= df_g[['Sitio','Country']].merge(df,how='left').Price` @Chris

Comment: @MartinBouhier I would need to see some sample data. Can you do `df.head(5)` and `df_g.head(5)` and the edit your question to include the sample data